# Connecting to localhost with React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I'm trying to fetch an json from a locally hosted express API using a react native fetch get request.
Our react native code is :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/listings")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJSON) => {
        console.log(responseJSON);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setListings(responseJSON);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

The following error is logged when we try to send the request:

```
Network request failed
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:30140:19 in <unknown>
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:31129:20 in <unknown>
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:31045:8 in _callTimer
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:31253:8 in Object.callTimers
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3213:30 in MessageQueue.__callFunction
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:2945:16 in <unknown>
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3167:12 in MessageQueue.__guard
at http://192.168.1.34:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:2944:13 in MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

When sending a get request from postman, the json is displayed so I am confused what is going wrong.

Comment: So is the request made from another device? In that case, `localhost` refers to that device's local host; not your computer's localhost, and you'll need to change localhost to your computer's local IP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the code below will help you. Enter it in terminal / cmd. Your emulator must be open.

```
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

Now your link should work `http://localhost:5000/api/listings`

If the first option did not work, try replacing your link by the link below:

`http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/listings`

This is due to the fact that Android does not understand localhost as your PC, for it, it is the localhost, so in the first choice we redirect the emulator door traffic for Windows / Linux. In the MacOS this error does not occur because the MacOS understands that the whole environment is localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below command to access localhost or 127.0.0.1 or your computer's ip

```
adb -s <device_name> reverse tcp:backend_port tcp:backend_port
```

Example:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8080tcp:8080
```

OR

```
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The development environment is a context and the android runner environment (if it is this) is another context.

If your backend is in node, you could use the [`serve` lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). It is SO independent and I think this is the easiest form.

You could configure the host in /etc/hosts/ file too, if you are using Linux (Debian-like).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use your IP address instead of localhost

```
http://localhost:5000/api/listings
```

to

```
http://IP-ADDRESS:5000/api/listings
```